# Customize mapstruct to ignore protobuff fields

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, grpc, mapstruct, grpc-java

Since I've noticed that MapStruct was updated to interact with Protobuff and its builder, I thought about migrating our services to fully use MapStruct.

However we're still writing manual conversions to protobuff messages because it's rather clumsy to write a full mapping, considering we have the target_unmapped = Error policy:

```
compileJava {
    options.compilerArgs += [
            '-Amapstruct.unmappedTargetPolicy=ERROR'
    ]
}
```

This means that even a rather simple mapping, of two classes with the same 6 identical field names (a throug f) looks like this:

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {...})
public interface ProtoMapperExample {

    @Mapping(target = "aBytes", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "bBytes", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "cBytes", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "dBytes", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "eBytes", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "fBytes", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "mergeFrom", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "clearField", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "clearOneof", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "unknownFields", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "mergeUnknownFields", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "allFields", ignore = true)
    ProtoMessage toMessage(Source s);

}
```

Which is honestly unacceptable. But the option of turning off the error is just as unacceptable.

Our solution was to simply not use MapStruct for this conversion, and I totally agree. It's cumbersome to say the least.

However if there were a way of configurating our mapper to ignore at least the latter 6 fields (mergeFrom, clearField, clearOneof, unknownFields, mergeUnknownFields, allFields) which one would assume and hope mapstruct did by default. Even that would be an improvement.

But we'd also need a way to ignore fields that end in "*Bytes".

Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already a MapStruct extension for Protobuf support which give you this feature right out-of-the-box. Community is actively maintaining this repo, so I would suggest to instead use this:
https://github.com/entur/mapstruct-spi-protobuf

Answer (score 3):

MapStruct does not support such ignoring, but you can use [Mapping Composition](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#mapping-composition) to simplify your mapper. All fields which need to be ignored can be gathered into one or several annotations.

**Create composite annotation for ignoring fields**

```java
import org.mapstruct.Mapping;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
@Mapping(target = "aBytes", ignore = true)
@Mapping(target = "bBytes", ignore = true)
@Mapping(target = "cBytes", ignore = true)
@Mapping(target = "dBytes", ignore = true)
@Mapping(target = "eBytes", ignore = true)
@Mapping(target = "fBytes", ignore = true)
@Mapping(target = "mergeFrom", ignore = true)
@Mapping(target = "clearField", ignore = true)
@Mapping(target = "clearOneof", ignore = true)
@Mapping(target = "unknownFields", ignore = true)
@Mapping(target = "mergeUnknownFields", ignore = true)
@Mapping(target = "allFields", ignore = true)
public @interface IgnoreProtobuff {
}
```

**Apply `@IgnoreProtobuff` to your mappers**

```java
@Mapper
public interface ProtoMapperExample {
    @IgnoreProtobuff
    ProtoMessage toMessage(Source s);
}
```

Comment: I did use this for quite some time, but the mapstruct-spi-protobuf is just better for the task. However this is a neat trick for other things, I still use it for some JPAs.